# How to solve linear systems of equations with variables in exponents of multiple terms?

Tags: linear-algebra

I "think" I understand solving linear system of equations, but this is a scenario I don't get. It's from an answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/20946) on StackExchange.

Take the equation for a point at $ f(x) = Ae^{Bx} $, but I don't know how to solve for A, B when functions are being subtracted as in $ f(x_1) - f(x_2) = something $